# What kinds of non-topological continuity concepts exist between partially-ordered sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-theory, domain-theory

Beside [Scott-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity), what other kinds of continuity concepts are there between partially-ordered sets that can be stated without recourse to topological concepts?

Comment: Arguably, measurability of functions is a measure-theoretic type of continuity.

Comment: This begs the question:  Why avoid topology?

Comment: @Aweygan: A topology does not always present itself readily.